# image not upload to php server , no response from servre on android

Tags: android

i doing app for uploading image to php server from android and the php server return a url as response for the request. i checked no problem in php server side it works fine for iphone. but in android i cannot get response. i have checked the php server my image is not uploaded. i do not know what is the problem in the code and how to get response. Is there is any setting needed? my code :

```
 public class upload extends Activity {
 InputStream is;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
 super.onCreate(icicle);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/imageq.png");
 ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bao);
 byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();
 String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new
 ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));
 try{
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/upload.php");
  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  Log.e("uri",""+httppost.getURI());
  Log.e("response",""+response);
  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
  is = entity.getContent();
  Log.e("is",""+is);
 }catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
 }
}
}
```

i get the above code from http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/
my log cat information:

```
05-11 10:09:39.488: ERROR/uri(1894): http://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/upload.php
05-11 10:09:39.488: ERROR/response(1894):    org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@44f73610
05-11 10:09:39.495: ERROR/is(1894): org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@44f1fc88
```

i print the getURI it returns what i give in the  httppost = new HttpPost("...."). this is not real response from server.  please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.telubi.connectivity;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

import com.cipl.TennisApp.Login;

public class FileUploader {

    private String Tag = "UPLOADER";
    private String urlString;// = "YOUR_ONLINE_PHP";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    String exsistingFileName;
    public String result;

    public String uploadImageData(String serverImageTag) {// Server image tag
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

            Log.e(Tag, "Inside second Method");

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    exsistingFileName));

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet

            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            if (serverImageTag.equalsIgnoreCase("courtImage")) {
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=courtImage[];filename="
                        + exsistingFileName + "" + lineEnd);
            } else if (serverImageTag.equalsIgnoreCase("userImage")) {
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: post-data; name=userImage[];filename="
                        + exsistingFileName + "" + lineEnd);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

            // create a buffer of maximum size

            int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            int maxBufferSize = 1000;
            // int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesAvailable];

            // read file and write it into form...

            int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bytesAvailable = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bytesAvailable);
            }

            // send multipart form data necessary after file data...

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));

            // String serverResponseCode = conn.
            // String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            while ((result = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                Log.v("result", "result " + result);

                    Login.fbResponse = result;

            }
            // close streams
            Log.e(Tag, "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            rd.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(Tag, "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }

        // Parsing has finished.
        return result;
    }

    public FileUploader(String existingFileName, String urlString) {

        this.exsistingFileName = existingFileName;
        this.urlString = urlString;

    }

}
```

I am using this code to upload image from device to php server by post method in this code you find a FilsUploader constructor pass file name you want upload and destination url (PHP server Url) for uploading file .I hope this is help.

Comment: i implement it. but i have doubt what is 'serverImageTag' and where the function uploadImageData is called.

Comment: uploadImageData this function call just after creating object of FileUploader class and serverImageTag is a tag provied by php server in my case if it is not require remove it for function and if conditions.